# Plotly: Is it possible to add a second y axis to plotly timeline?

Tags: python, plot, graph, plotly

I am trying to add a second y axis to a plotly figure. I could not find any hint in the documentation. Is that possible?

```
  fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="start", x_end="end", y="duration")

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed", type='category')

fig.write_html('fig.html', auto_open=True)
```

[image]

In the right part of the figure I would like to have another y axis showing information as a string.

I would be very thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#multiple-y-axes-and-plotly-express this should help

Comment: @edgj4718 Information as a string? Don't you want the secondary axis to be associated with actual traces in the figure?

Comment: I want both the "yaxis" and the "secondary yaxis" to be related with the "start" and "end" values. Do you think that is possible by using the same x_start and x_end but different y in two traces and then plot these two traces in one figure?

Comment: @edgj4718 How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately it did not. Actually I wanted exactly the picture above with an additional Yaxis in the right. The Yaxis in the right would show almost the same information as the one in the left. The one in the left actually shows the difference between Start and End time (the duration). The one in the right would show the CycleTime of a specific machine within that duration. For example, producing a piece at machine x lasted 200s(information on the left). The machine work on this piece 170s(information on the right) .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to add a secondary y axis to a plotly timeline. But not *directly* using `px.timeline`. You won't be able to skip the 'standard' approach for a secondary axis using:

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
```

But once you've done that, you can build several `px.timeline` objects using:

```
fx1 = px.timeline(df1, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
```

And then "steal" components from there, such as:

```
fx1.data[0]

fig.layout.xaxis = fx1.layout.xaxis
```

And then include them in your first `fig` object with:

```
fig.add_trace(
    fx2.data[0],
    secondary_y=True,
)
```

Here's an example:

[image]

And here's the complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Completion_pct=50),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Completion_pct=25),
#     dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Completion_pct=75),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-04-02', Finish='2009-05-11', Completion_pct=75)
])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job D", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-12', Completion_pct=50),
    dict(Task="Job E", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-01', Completion_pct=25),
    dict(Task="Job F", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-08-01', Completion_pct=75)
])


# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fx1 = px.timeline(df1, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
fx2 = px.timeline(df2, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")

# fx1 = px.timeline(df1, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Task")
# fx2 = px.timeline(df2, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Task")

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    fx1.data[0],
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    fx2.data[0],
    secondary_y=True,
)

fig.layout.xaxis = fx1.layout.xaxis

# fx1.show()
# fx2.show()
fig.data[0].opacity = 0.2
fig.data[1].width = 0.5
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

My timeline had multiple elements in its `data` attribute. In my case I had to loop through fx1.data to add each trace tot `fig` as such:

```
for trace in fx1.data:
    fig.add_trace(trace, secondary_y=False)
```